# SD.remove() is not removing a file on Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I have two sketches I am running on an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). The first one dumps a file to the serial if it exists. This is one of the examples that comes with the Arduino, but I've modified it as such:

```
/*
    SD card file dump

    This example shows how to read a file from the SD card using the
    SD library and send it over the serial port.

    The circuit:
    * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
    ** MOSI - pin 11
    ** MISO - pin 12
    ** CLK - pin 13
    ** CS - pin 4

    Created  22 December 2010 by Limor Fried
    Modified 9 Apr 2012 by Tom Igoe

    This example code is in the public domain.
 */

#include <SD.h>

// On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. Note that even if it's not
// used as the CS pin, the hardware CS pin (10 on most Arduino boards,
// 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output or the SD library
// functions will not work.
const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup()
{
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // Wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only.
    }

    Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
    // Make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
    // output, even if you don't use it:
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

    // See if the card is present and can be initialized:
    if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
        Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
        // Don't do anything more:
        return;
    }
    Serial.println("card initialized.");

    // Open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
    // so you have to close this one before opening another.
    File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt");

    // If the file is available, write to it:
    if (dataFile) {
        while (dataFile.available()) {
          Serial.write(dataFile.read());
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }
    // If the file isn't open, pop up an error:
    else {
        Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
    }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

My other sketch is supposed to remove a file. When I run this remove sketch it says there is no file found. Yet I can continually run the above sketch and dump the contents to the serial. My remove sketch is as follows:

```
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
    // Make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
    // output, even if you don't use it:
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

    if(SD.exists("datalog.txt"))
    {
        SD.remove("datalog.txt");
        Serial.println("file removed");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("no file to remove");
    }
}

void loop(){

}
```

Am I missing something here?

Just after posting this I realized I was not making this remove sketch fault tolerant and added the following code after the `pinmode` line:

```
  // See if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
      Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
      // don't do anything more:
      return;
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
```

Thus the new remove sketch was as follows:

```
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
    // Make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
    // output, even if you don't use it:
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

    // See if the card is present and can be initialized:
    if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
        Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
        // Don't do anything more:
        return;
    }
    Serial.println("card initialized.");

    if(SD.exists("datalog.txt"))
    {
        SD.remove("datalog.txt");
        Serial.println("file removed");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("no file to remove");
    }
}

void loop(){

}
```

Upon running that sketch it now removes the files. Why is it that new version works but the old one did not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `SD.begin()` doesn't make it fault tolerant. It initializes the library. You need to call that before calling other functions. From the [Reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDbegin):

> begin() Initializes the SD library and card. This begins use of the
>   SPI bus (digital pins 11, 12, and 13 on most Arduino boards; 50, 51,
>   and 52 on the Mega) and the chip select pin, which defaults to the
>   hardware SS pin (pin 10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega).

Comment: Ahhh, I was thinking that did nothing more than see if the card was ready to go, didn't realize it was doing that AND providing status.  My bad....